# ElasticSearch fuzzy query and case sensitivity

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I've just started looking into ElasticSearch and had some questions on the fuzzy query.  Let's say I had a document like this:

```
{ "name": "Frankie's Hot Dogs" }
```

Using the fuzzy query, if I searched using the following parameters, I'd receive no results:

```
"fuzzy": {
  "name": {
    "value": "FRANKIES",
    "fuzziness": 2
  }
}
```

Is this the expected behavior?  I thought that since the field was defaulted to the Standard Analyzer that the name field would be tokenized and lowercased to something like:

```
["frankie's", "hot", "dogs"]
```

So wouldn't searching through a fuzzy query automatically lowercase your search terms?  Or is this not the case?

Finally, does anyone have any suggestions on querying the data so that FRANKIES would actually return a hit?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use fuzzy_like_this query

```
 "query": {
    "fuzzy_like_this" : {
        "fields" : ["name"],
        "like_text" : "FRANKIES"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked.  Can you please explain why this worked while the plain fuzzy query did not?

Comment: For those reading this answer, you should note that the fuzzy_like_this query, as well as the fuzzy_like_this_filed query, were deprecated in ElasticSearch 1.6.